# How could I draw text in an 'info bubble' with libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making an android game using libgdx where there are textures on the screen which represent people. When you touch a person sprite I want a little info bubble to pop above their head displaying some information about them in text form (something a bit like how speech is shown in a comic book). The sprites move and the info should follow above them until it is tapped closed.

I have got something working at the moment, which is really basic. I have rectangle that is part of the ShapeRenderer that is drawn, I then draw the text over the top using the batch draw.

I want the rectangle to have curved edges and resize depending on the size of the text but before I start writing something.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I should go about it? Should I try and use dialog from scene2d and render my whole game using scene2d? From what I have seen it seems good for menus but I'm not sure about rendering a whole game using it.

Or is there something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so two parts to this;

> rectangle to have curved edges and resize depending on the size of the text

This sounds great for [9patch](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/NinePatch.html)! 9patch can scale up textures using only certain portions of the image, so you get to keep undistorted smooth corners when scaling both vertically and horizontally.

> depending on the size of the text

LibGDX has a useful tool for this, [BitmapFonts](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.html). We can call :
`font.draw(Batch batch, java.lang.CharSequence str, float x, float y, float targetWidth, int halign, boolean wrap)`. 
Then to find out how tall we need to draw the box after specifying the width with `targetWidth`by capturing information from the GlyphLayout object returned.

... However we have already drawn it so this is no good!
Instead we can use a GlyphLayout object directly and then call `font.draw(Batch batch, GlyphLayout layout, float x, float y)`. Once we have added all the text and more importantly drawn the background.

```
//It might look something like this
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
...
int textBoxBuffer = 5; // Allow for box to surround the text
int textBoxWidth = 80; // the default width of the textbox
void drawSpeech(String str, int x, int y){
    GlyphLayout layout = new GlyphLayout(str, x, y, textBoxWidth , Align.left, true);
    draw9PatchTextBox(x - textBoxBuffer, y - textBoxBuffer,
                      layout.width + textBoxBuffer, layout.height + textBoxBuffer);
    font.draw(batch, layout, x, y);
}
```